# Error when trying to view Admin page on Prestashop 1.6 setTemplateDir()

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

When trying to visit a Prestashop admin page I get this error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplateDir() on null in /var/www/vhosts/..../classes/controller/AdminController.php on line 425

I've tried doing a fresh install of the base files and then adding back the user generated files, site config, and the custom theme for the front end, and the issue perists.

Comment: Hello. Which specific admin controller are you visiting??

Comment: Not sure what you mean? the one that comes with PrestaShop?